# Finding maximum/minimum distance of two rows in a matrix using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, euclidean-distance

Say we have a matrix `m x n` where the number of rows of the matrix is very big. If we assume each row is a vector, then how could one find the maximum/minimum distance between vectors in this matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html).  This computes pairs of Euclidean distances between unique combinations of observations like @seb has suggested, but this is already built into MATLAB.  Your matrix is already formatted nicely for `pdist` where each row is an observation and each column is a variable.

Once you do apply `pdist`, apply [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) so that you can display the distance between pairwise entries in a more pleasant matrix form.  The `(i,j)` entry for each value in this matrix tells you the distance between the i<sup>th</sup> and j<sup>th</sup> row.  Also note that this matrix will be symmetric and the distances along the diagonal will inevitably equal to 0, as any vector's distance to itself must be zero.  If your minimum distance between two different vectors were zero, if we were to search this matrix, then it may possibly report a self-distance instead of the actual distance between two different vectors.  As such, in this matrix, you should set the diagonals of this matrix to `NaN` to avoid outputting these.

As such, assuming your matrix is `A`, all you have to do is this:

```
distValues = pdist(A); %// Compute pairwise distances
minDist = min(distValues); %// Find minimum distance
maxDist = max(distValues); %// Find maximum distance
distMatrix = squareform(distValues); %// Prettify
distMatrix(logical(eye(size(distMatrix)))) = NaN; %// Ignore self-distances
[minI,minJ] = find(distMatrix == minDist, 1); %// Find the two vectors with min. distance
[maxI,maxJ] = find(distMatrix == maxDist, 1); %// Find the two vectors with max. distance
```

---

`minI, minJ, maxI, maxJ` will return the two rows of `A` that produced the smallest distance and the largest distance respectively.  Note that with the [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) statement, I have made the second parameter 1 so that it only returns **one** pair of vectors that have this minimum / maximum distance between each other.  However, if you omit this parameter, then it will return **all possible** pairs of rows that share this same distance, but you will get duplicate entries as the `squareform` is symmetric.  If you want to escape the duplication, set either the upper triangular half, or lower triangular half of your `squareform` matrix to `NaN` to tell MATLAB to skip searching in these duplicated areas.  You can use MATLAB's [`tril`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) or [`triu`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) commands to do that.  Take note that either of these methods by default will include the diagonal of the matrix and so there won't be any extra work here.  As such, try something like:

```
distValues = pdist(A); %// Compute pairwise distances
minDist = min(distValues); %// Find minimum distance
maxDist = max(distValues); %// Find maximum distance
distMatrix = squareform(distValues); %// Prettify
distMatrix(triu(true(size(distMatrix)))) = NaN; %// To avoid searching for duplicates
[minI,minJ] = find(distMatrix == minDist); %// Find pairs of vectors with min. distance
[maxI,maxJ] = find(distMatrix == maxDist); %// Find pairs of vectors with max. distance
```

Judging from your application, you just want to find one such occurrence only, so let's leave it at that, but I'll put that here for you in case you need it.

Comment: +1 Great answer, whith includes many subtleties (`find` returns more than one value, second output of `max`/`min` hard to use here)

Comment: @rayryeng thanks a lot for the complete answer. Actually, I want to have all such min/max.

Comment: @Royeh - You're very welcome!  The second solution I provided should give you such.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You mean the max/min distance between any 2 rows? If so, you can try that:

```
numRows = 6;
A = randn(numRows, 100);      %// Example of input matrix


%// Compute distances between each combination of 2 rows
T = nchoosek(1:numRows,2);  %// pairs of indexes for all combinations of 2 rows
for k=1:length(T)
    d(k) = norm(A(T(k,1),:)-A(T(k,2),:));
end

%// Find min/max distance
[~, minIndex] = min(d);
[~, maxIndex] = max(d);

T(minIndex,:)   %// Displays indexes of the 2 rows with minimum distance
T(maxIndex,:)   %// Displays indexes of the 2 rows with maximum distance
```